# Redefine \cref for non-English languages

Tags: cross-referencing, languages, cleveref, translations

Would it be possible to define another command `\frcref` that is similar to `\cref`, but when it is called, e.g. `\frcref{ch:chapter1}`, it displays the French word "Chapitre" instead of the English word "Chapter" in the hyperlink? (`\cref` should still print the English words.)

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage[french]{cleveref}`?

Comment: But then all \cref would be in French right? I only need some of them, because there is both Fr and En in my document.

Comment: Then please update your question with this important information about multiple languages in the same document

Comment: For example, do please confirm that you load the `hyperref` package as well. Do you load the `babel` package? If so, with which language option(s)? And, with which options (if any) do you load the `cleveref` package?

Answer (score 11):

You can just surround the `\cref` command with e.g. `\foreignlanguage`, provided you have passed your languages to both `babel` and `cleveref`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish,french,main=british]{babel}
\usepackage[danish,french,english]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\label{chap-test}

\Cref{chap-test}

\foreignlanguage{danish}{\Cref{chap-test}}

\foreignlanguage{french}{\Cref{chap-test}}


\end{document}
```

Note `cleveref` with `french` does not like certain characters, including `:` in labels.

You can capture this in new macros such as

```
\newcommand{\fCref}[1]{\foreignlanguage{french}{\Cref{#1}}}
```

However, below I have gone further and defined a command `\newcreflang` with the effect that

```
\newcreflang{f}{french}
```

defines both `\fcref` and `\fCref` in one go.  This command could be extended further to create analogues of other macros from `cleveref`.

[image: Extended sample]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[swedish,french,main=british]{babel}
\usepackage[swedish,french,english]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\@mlcref}[3]{\foreignlanguage{#1}{\@cref{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\newcreflang}[2]{%
\csgdef{@#1cref}##1##2{\@mlcref{#2}{##1}{##2}}%
\csgdef{#1cref}##1{\csuse{@#1cref}{cref}{##1}}%
\csgdef{#1Cref}##1{\csuse{@#1cref}{Cref}{##1}}}
\makeatother

\newcreflang{sw}{swedish}
\newcreflang{f}{french}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\label{chap-test}

\Cref{chap-test}

\swCref{chap-test} or ``\swcref{chap-test,chap-test-2}'' or
``\swcref{chap-test,chap-test-2,chap-test-3}''

\fCref{chap-test} or
``\fcref{chap-test,chap-test-2}'' or
``\fcref{chap-test,chap-test-2,chap-test-3}''

\chapter{Test 2}
\label{chap-test-2}

\chapter{Test 3}
\label{chap-test-3}

\end{document}
```

(I have switched the other language from danish to swedish, as there is currently an error in the danish set-up in `cleveref` that I will report to the package author.)

Comment: @Marijn I get the following error: `Missing \endcsname inserted`. Any idea where it may come from?

Comment: @JoeDumars did you try the exact code that Andrew Swann posted? Did you get any errors there? Or did you get an error when you tried to copy it into your actual document? In that case you might have copied it incompletely or in the wrong position.

Comment: @Marijn I get errors when I copy it in my document. I don't think I have copied it incompletely. Concerning the position, I have multiple packages in my document. Where should I copy the Adrew Swann's code?

Comment: REgarding ARabic language definitions:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507166/defining-a-new-language-in-cref