# Defining a new language in Cref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, arabic, varioref

I am preparing a document whose main language is arabic, I am using babel+Lualatex
I followed the procedure discussed in [Redefine \cref for non-English languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482143/redefine-cref-for-non-english-languages)

However, it gives an error saying "unknown option arabic", is there a way to define a new language for Clever ref and Varioref ref?? Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} % Set paper layout
%======================================================================================================
%Babel Package Settings%
%======================================================================================================
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic}

\usepackage [arabic]{varioref} %  add "on the preceding page", "on the following page", or on the page number to a reference

\usepackage[arabic,english]{cleveref}
%==================================================
%Start actual document %
%===================================================
\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{سييسسيبيسب}
بلبيللبيبلبي
\section{بيسيبلبيبلبيل}\label{بندددد}
البند رقم
\ref{بندددد} 
صفحة
\pageref{بندددد}
البند
~\vref{بندددد}

ب
\cref{بندددد}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Languages are supported by `varioref` (and `cleveref`) through defined options. Languages that aren't set up in this way can't be given as an "option" to the package even though you can nevertheless set them up in the preamble of your document.

I could add an "arabic" option to the package if somebody provides me with the right textual strings, i.e., I would need the texts in the following definitions be replaced with Arabic words:

```
\DeclareOption{arabic}
  {\vref@addto\extrasarabic{%
    \def\reftextfaceafter {on the \reftextvario{facing}{next} page}%
    \def\reftextfacebefore{on the \reftextvario{facing}{preceding}
                           page}%
    \def\reftextafter     {on the \reftextvario{following}{next} page}%
    \def\reftextbefore    {on the \reftextvario{preceding}{previous} page}%
    \def\reftextcurrent   {on \reftextvario{this}{the current} page}%
    \def\reftextfaraway#1{on page~\pageref{#1}}%
    \def\reftextpagerange#1#2{on pages~\pageref{#1}--\pageref{#2}}%
    \def\reftextlabelrange#1#2{\ref{#1} to~\ref{#2}}%
  }}
```

after which `\usepackage[arabic]{varioref}` would work.

With `cleveref` the situation is similar, but you would need to talk the developer of that package to get this language supported as an option.

### Test document

As requested in a comment, here is a test document which (I think) exercises all cases.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{varioref}

\begin{document}

          \section{A} \label{A1} \section{A2} \label{A2}

\newpage  \section{B} \label{B1} \section{B2} \label{B2}

See \vref{A1} ; See \vref{A2} ; See \vrefrange{A1}{A2} 

See \vref{B1} ; See \vref{B2} ; See \vrefrange{B1}{B2}

Current page: \pageref{B1} ; \pageref{B2}

See \vref{C1} ; See \vref{C2} ; See \vrefrange{C1}{C2} 

See \vref{D1} ; See \vref{D2} ; See \vrefrange{D1}{D2} 

Longer ranges: \vrefrange{A1}{C1} ; \vpagerefrange{B1}{D2}

\newpage  \section{C} \label{C1} \section{C2} \label{C2}

\newpage  \section{D} \label{D1} \section{D2} \label{D2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: According to cleveref manual: Cleveref supports a number of languages other than English, and also supports  the babel and polyglossia packages  for  those  languages.   Either  pass the  desired  language  as  an  option  to cleveref,  or  pass  it  as  a  global  option to\document class. Passing a language to the document class is not preferred. However, do you happen to have the code required for declaring a new language as an option, since this is already possible?

Comment: @Silva sure cleveref supports a number of languages, but not necessary all of babel and what it doesn't support you can't pass as an option to it.  As a user you can't declare a new language for either ot the two packages; it has to be done by the maintainer of the package, there is no real interface for it.

Comment: I prepared the Arabic translation. However, do you happen to have any sample code on which I can test the proposed translation (examine all cases), only to make sure it is working as it should?

Comment: @Silva done. If your translation is ready, please send it to the email address in the file and indicate if you want your contact details shown in the doc or not.

Comment: Final Query, for the lines having 2 definitions, when is each one used, for example :"\reftextvario{facing}{next}", when is the term "facing" used and when is  the term"next" used?? Is there a purpose for having 2 terms with the same meaning? The same query goes for the rest of the definitions.

Comment: ,regarding the optional argument (Above), (Below), do they require any translations or are they obtained from the Babel package? If any additional translations are required, just provide the code and I'll do the translations.

Comment: @Silva this is actually all described in the documentation which you get if you run `texdoc varioref`. But briefly \reftextvario will select one of the arguments in alteration: each time a \vref or \vpageref is used some internal counter is incremented and if the counter has an odd value the first arg is used otherwise the second. It is just there to produce a little less monotone text strings. The optional arguments contain what the user puts into them in the document so nothing to translate here. Again pleasee read docu.